# Google's OAuth2ForDevices doesn't support the Drive API yet?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I was scribbling some code for OAuthenticating my development account with an active Google Drive API Client App in a  headless Raspberry Pi.

I'm using the py-gaugette module (https://github.com/guyc/py-gaugette) in a python3/pip3 environment.

The code is as follows:

```
import gaugette.oauth
CLIENT_ID = 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxx'
CLIENT_SCOPE = ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.files']
# CLIENT_SCOPE = ['profile', 'email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']

oauth = gaugette.oauth.DeviceOAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, CLIENT_SCOPE)
if not oauth.has_token():
    user_code = oauth.get_user_code()
    # print "Go to %s and enter the code %s" % (oauth.verification_url, user_code)
    print("Go to " + oauth.verification_url + " and enter the code: " + user_code)
    oauth.get_new_token()
```

The program works fine for the Calendar API and couple other scopes of other APIs. However, the support for Drive API is not clearly specified. I tried using the relevant Drive API Scopes and this is the error message:

```
400

b'{\n  "error" : "invalid_scope"\n}'
```

Also, on the contrary I saw the page https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices mentioning some experimentation for Drive API.

*My goal is to authenticate the app for Read & Write permissions at the App Folder Level*

Can someone help me out here?Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are many different ways to use oauth. can you update your question to explain who the users are, which accounts they need to access, will your app be distributed vs is it personal.

Comment: i think this is more of a library and implementation problem than the Drive API itself.

Comment: Hi, I have observed similar issues in the Google Drive Forums as well. Apparently, they have not yet taken the opportunity to consider addressing the issue. We are very clear about the client app's logic. Need help specifically from the API support side. 
*Why is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.files" scope not yet supported in OAuthForDevices? yet there's a documentation*

Answer (score 0):

The [Drive Files API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/#Files) is supported.

You are allowed to request "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file".